# How to setup multiple domains on AEM as a cloud service on dispatcher

Tags: configuration, cloud, aem, dispatcher, multiple-domains

I want to set up a multiple domain in aem as a cloud service how can i achieve this.
I  have create a two vhost and two rewrite files but only one vhost is get accesible

Is any one have done this configuration please provide support for this

Answer (score 1):

For AEMaaCS, you define vhost settings in `src/conf.d/available_vhosts` and create a symlink under `src/conf.d/enabled_vhosts`

There is then default.vhost which is catch all configurations i.e if you dont have domain based vhost defined, it will be rendered by default.vhost.

These files are included in alphabetical order, so if for example you name your files as `asite.vhost` and `siteb.vhost`, the order in which the files will be included is `asite.vhost, default.vhost and last siteb.vhost`. In this case any request for siteb will be handled by `default.vhost`.

In most of mine multisite dispatcher configurations, I use `00_<site 1>.vhost, 00_<site2>.vhost` to ensure that my sites are loaded before default.vhost.

In case this is not the case for you, can you share your configurations.